# Error Importing GTKMOZEMBED

Tags: python, firefox, gtk, embed

I am new to Ubuntu/Python. I am developing an application that opens a web browser and displays Google Maps in it. After my search I found out that gtkmozembed + Glade will do so. But when I try to run an example code like this one :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PythonRecipes/WebBrowser

I get the error "**ImportError: No module named gtkmozembed**"

I have installed the gnome-python-extras & python-gtkmozembed from debian but still I get the error.

Any type of help will be greatly helpful to me . Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can see where Python is looking for imports by doing the following at a console prompt:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
```

The displayed list of locations that results is where Python will look for files to import.  This list is also known as your Python path.

You can now verify if the install location of gtkmozembed really isn't in your Python path, and if it isn't just a typo somewhere (you didn't say you installed it) then resolve it by either (a) re-installing it to somewhere in your Python path (typically site-packages, though this varies per OS/distribution), or (b) setting the PYTHONPATH env variable to include where it is installed.